# Java, save random generated number several times to use them later

Tags: java

I'm making a program which generates numbers within a range (0 to 100) several times in a loop.
I need to save those numbers every time are generated to make the program output something and to put them on a estadistic-like thing.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList<Integer> temps = new ArrayList(); //will contain all temperatures
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Set the ammount of minutes that the program lasts");
    int minutes = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter max temperature");
    int maxT = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter min temperature");
    int minT = scan.nextInt();

    int count = 0;

    while(minutes > 0) {
        minutes--;
        pause();
        int newTemp = (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 100)); //Generate random number
        temps.add(newTemp); // random number to arraylist
        if(newTemp > maxT) //if new temperature is above the limits
            count++;
        if(count>=3) { //if the temperature has gone above the limits more than 3 times
            System.out.println("ALARMA!!!");
            break; //break loop
        }
        else if(newTemp < maxT && newTemp > minT) //if new temperature is inside the limits
        {
            System.out.println("REVISAR SISTEMES");
            break; //break loop
        }
        else if (newTemp < minT)
        {
            System.out.println("EMERGENCIA ACABADA. Tot correcte");
            break; //break loop
        }
    }
    System.out.println(temps);
}

public static void pause() {
    try        
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } 
    catch(InterruptedException ex) 
    {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a `List` to add the generated numbers.

Comment: What is estadistic?

Comment: Statistic, sorry

Comment: Looks like you are trying to mock up a temperature sensor.
Could you give some more detail?

Comment: Exactly like you said, searcot jabali. It's a temperature sensor.

Comment: The random function can generate an infinite number of random numbers.
What is your limiting factor?
Time? Number of readings?

Comment: The limiting factor is this:`(counter< Nmax);` `final int Nmax = 24;`Also `int counter = 0`

Comment: You are already saving the random numbers. What is your question? What is wrong with the code you have already?

Comment: Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a couple of lines to make use of the MAX Temp & MIN Temp
Now the program will exit if the generated temperature falls outside the given limits more than 3 times
Instead of exiting (break) you can do whatever you need to in that code block

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class myRan {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<Integer> temps = new ArrayList(); //will contain all temperatures
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Set the ammount of minutes that the program lasts");
        int minutes = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter max temperature");
        int maxT = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter min temperature");
        int minT = scan.nextInt();

        int count = 0;

        while(minutes > 0) {
            minutes--;
            pause();
            int newTemp = (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 100)); //Generate random number
            temps.add(newTemp); // random number to arraylist
            if(newTemp > maxT || newTemp < minT) //if new temperature is out of limits
                count++;
            if(count>3) { //if the temperature has gone out of limits more than 3 times
                System.out.println("ALERT! Issue at time :" + minutes);
                break; //add your code for alert here
            }
        }
        System.out.println(temps);

    }

    public static void pause() {
        try        
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } 
        catch(InterruptedException ex) 
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class myRan {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<Integer> rands = new ArrayList();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Set the ammount of minutes that the program lasts");
        int minutes = scan.nextInt();


        while(minutes > 0) {
            pause();
            rands.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 100));
            minutes--;
        }
        System.out.println(rands);

    }

    public static void pause() {
        try        
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } 
        catch(InterruptedException ex) 
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }


}
```

To make it generate a random number every minute change **Thread.sleep(1000);**
to **Thread.sleep(60000);**

Keep in mind that it will then run for as many minutes as you specified.

Comment: I discarded the MIN & MAX since you stated that you need them in the range of 0 -100. When you generate random number with **ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 100)** it automatically generates only those numbers in that range

Comment: Oh ok, i didn't tried that. I think I get it, thanks :)

Comment: So, then i add whatever i want the program to do with the numbers inside the while, right?

Comment: Thats pretty much it.
I added another answer to take into consideration the '3 temperatures out side the max & min range'